# Display Images Using Android Native Library

Tags: android

I want to improve the performance of my app by displaying images using android native library in C language.This issue is due to large amount of memory required by the images in my app.

Comment: I totally doubt that you will improve anything this way. Canvas is a very performant API.

Comment: I think android app get only limitted size for the application, so I need to increase the size that is not just limitted to 25MB or to heap size so that loading of images may not take a lot of time which can be decreased by native libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet there's no need to do that. Android Bitmaps are already written in C and, in most cases, already hardware accelerated. It would be nice to know, what are you going to achieve, and what effort did you put already.

edit:

So, if you think about having a lot of images in the memory, you can use native memory. The trick is that you can use Java methods for drawing (which is convenient) and native memory for storing unused images (which is fast and big). You can try using NativeBuffer library for such task: http://code.google.com/p/native-buffer/

The usage is pretty straightforward. You have to preload all images to the buffer. Then, when you need an image, you can load it from the buffer. You can do this even in draw() method. It's insanely fast comparing to sdcard.

Of course be aware that NativeBuffer uses C-style allocations and you may run out of system memory. It's not going to throw OutOFMemoryError, but force stop your app without asking. NativeLibrary contains some utilities for checking available memory, but you have to manage it yourself.

Comment: I have an application like talking tom which take lot of time for different animations.What else can I do to improve my performance?

Comment: please edit your question (add info about larger amount of memory needed) so you can get more answers and some upvotes on your question. Cheers